# In Ruby, how can I save float value with only 1 digit after the decimal point?

Tags: ruby

I have a variable named "rating" of type float. It has many digits after the decimal point.
I want to save it to have only one digit. How can I do it?

```
rating = 4.80999994277954
```

I would like it to be

```
rating = 4.8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Float#round](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Float.html#method-i-round) to round (rather than truncate) your Float to the precision you want. For example:

```
rating = (4.80999994277954).round(1)
#=> 4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
rating = rating.round(1)
```